# Error in writing a action for making call when button is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios

I placed a textfield for entering a number to make a call , and i placed a Button for a call so that if i pressed that button i need to make a call for the number which i entered in the textfield.
can any 1 help me in the coding . thanks!
I tried like this!

```
    NSString *pn = [@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:phoneField.text];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pn]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating pn string incorrectly. Try:

```
NSString *pn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneField.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pn]];
```

Comment: its not working for me.What i am doing is i am writing in a action method and calling that action method for Button.